# C++ Instantiate, inside another class, a class-type variable from a group of classes with same constructor

Tags: c++, class, constructor

I am not advanced in C++. Suppose I have a group of classes, from `A` to whatever (the number will grow in time), that use the same type of constructor. Suppose it looks like this:

```
class A
{
private:
    double m_x, m_y;
public:
    A(const double &x, double &y, const short &n) { ... };
};
```

Each of these classes have the same `m_x, m_y` variables, but they calculate it differently. Now there's another class, say `Bla`, who needs to use the constructors from the previous group of classes, something like this:

```
class Bla
{
private:
    Class m_class;
public:
    Bla(const double &x, const double &y, const double &z, const short &i)
    {
        switch (i)
        {
        case 1: m_class = A::A(...); break;
        case 2: m_class = B::B(...); break;
        ...
        }
    }
};
```

The `switch (i)` in the constructor chooses one of the group's constructor according to `i`. How can I make the `Class m_class` variable inside `Bla` to be consistent with the `switch (i)` in the constructor? What type of variable should I choose, or how?

Alternatively, `m_class` only needs to hold the `m_x, m_y` variables coming from one of the classes in the group, to be further processed/calculated/etc, is there another method of doing this? I hope I managed to be clear about this.

Comment: It sounds like you need a factory function.

Comment: And, first of all, a base common superclass holding `m_x` and `m_y`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could have an interface class with those common member variables

```
class I
{
public:
    virtual ~I() = default;
protected:
    double m_x, m_y;
};
```

Then derive your concrete classes from that, each of which will populate `m_x` and `m_y` differently.

```
class A : public I
{
public:
    A(const double &x, double &y, const short &n) { ... };
};
```

Then your `Bla` constructor essentially acts as a factory and makes specific types of `I` depending on your `i` parameter

```
class Bla
{
private:
    std::unique_ptr<I> m_class;
public:
    Bla(const double &x, const double &y, const double &z, const short &i)
    {
        switch (i)
        {
        case 1: m_class = std::unique_ptr<I>(new A(...)); break;
        case 2: m_class = std::unique_ptr<I>(new B(...)); break;
        ...
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. A question, though. I didn't know about `unique_ptr`, I just read about it. It says there I don't have to use `delete` for it, but does this also mean that I can use it dynamically, at runtime, without headaches? Cleaning up for pointers is not something I really like...

Comment: I see now the edit to include the destructor. I marked this as the answer.

Comment: Yes that is right, `unique_ptr` allows you to still get polymorphic behavior (i.e. using an interface) but you don't have to `delete` anything by hand

Answer (score 1):

You can derive those classes from one common class. For example:

```
class Test {
    double Val1, Val2;
public:
    Test() {}
};

class A: public Test { 
    /* constructor and class-specific variables only,
       don't declare Val1 & Val2 here */
}
```

Then, make `m_class` a pointer to `Test` and instantiate the classes in your `switch` with `new`.