# C++ Derived classes won't work without default parameters, even then wrong

Tags: c++, class

Suppose I have a base class `A`, two derived classes `B` and `C` which are `virtual public A`, and a final class `D`, which is `public B, public C`. I tried to make a working code for this:

```
#include <iostream>

class A
{
protected:
    int m_x;
public:
    A(int a): m_x {2 * a} { std::cout << "A()" << '\n'; }
};

class B : virtual public A
{
private:
    int m_y, m_z;
public:
    B(int a): m_y {a * a}
    {
        m_z = 2 * m_y + 1;
        A(m_z);
        std::cout << "B()" << '\n';
    }
    int getVal() { return m_y; }
};

class C : virtual public A
{
private:
    int m_p, m_q;
public:
    C(int a): m_p {1 - a}
    {
        m_q = m_p - 3 * a;
        A(m_q);
        std::cout << "C()" << '\n';
    }
    int getVal() { return m_p; }
};

class D : public B, public C
{
private:
    int m_w;
public:
    D(int a, int b)
    {
        switch (b)
        {
        case 1: { B(a); break; }
        case 2: { C(a); break; }
        }
        m_w = m_x * a;
        std::cout << "D()" << '\n';
    }

    int getVal() { return m_z; }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    D d {5, 1};
    std::cout << d.getVal() << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

All classes normally have their own `.h` and `.cpp` file, I compacted it a bit and the formulas are pure fiction. The short story is that `A` acts as an interface class who has `m_x` as a common variable for both `B` and `C`, to be used and modified as needed, while `D` uses `A`'s variable to further calculate the desired `m_w`. The two virtual classes are called on a need basis, from `D`.

My problem: I can't compile the above if no default parameters are given, but if they are, the results are wrong.

a) As it is (no default parameters), first error line:
`16:29 no matching function for call to A::A()`

b) No default parameters, change line 19 to `A::A(m_z)`:
`cannot call constructor ‘B::A’ directly [-fpermissive]`
(I think this makes sense, no such thing as `B::A`)

c) With default parameters: A=2, B=3, C=4, outputs:

```
A()
A()
B()
A()
C()
A()
A()
B()
D()
10
```

which looks awful enough (I don't know why so many calls), but it should also be:
`B(5)` =>
`m_y = 5 * 5 = 25`
`m_z = 2 * 25 + 1 = 51`
`A(51)` =>
`m_x = 2 * 51 = 102`
finally:
`m_w = 102 * 5 = 510`

...shouldn't it? Can someone please tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Do you really need your classes be derived as `virtual public`? Won't just `public` be enough?

Comment: @ForceBru `A` splits to `B` and `C`, which group to `D`, both. I understand this is the so called "diamond problem and `virtual` is supposed to fix it. If I am wrong, I'll gladly change it.

Comment: Calling `A(m_z)` in your initializer for `B` doesn't do what you think it does ...

Comment: @donkopotamus I think it changex `m_x` according to `m_z`, but if it doesnt do that, then what?

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen `A(m_z)` inside the constructor body of `B` creates a new local instance of class `A`. This instance is not related to the one that is currently constructed with `B` constructor.

Comment: @grek40 So then, if I make an `A` variable (reference, pointer, something) and assign it `A(m_z)`, will that force `A()` to be calculated and change `m_x` according to `m_z`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to call base class constructors in the initializer list, not in the constructor body.

Replace

```
B(int a): m_y {a * a}
{
    m_z = 2 * m_y + 1;
    A(m_z);
    std::cout << "B()" << '\n';
}
```

By

```
B(int a): A(2 * a * a + 1), m_y {a * a}
{
    m_z = 2 * m_y + 1;
    std::cout << "B()" << '\n';
}
```

And so on.

In class `D` you need to call constructors for `A`, `B` and `C`, since C++ doesn't allow second guessing, whether the `A` constructor would be called from `B` or `C` when `D` is created.

---

**Take 2**

Since you actually want `D` to conditionally construct an instance of `B` or `C`, you need to reorganize your design.

> Suppose I have temperature readings (A) from different countries (B,
>   C, etc), and I have to filter/present/display them on
>   screen/graph/somehow (D) (just an example).

So you have different measurement units of temperatures and you want to display them together in the same measurement unit. For my personal convenience, I say that the target unit is °C.

Lets design a temperature class and some helpers and factory methods

```
int CelsiusToFahrenheit(int c)
{ return /* somehow calculate F from c */; }

int FahrenheitToCelsius(int f)
{ return /* somehow calculate °C from f */; }


class Temperature
{
protected:
    int m_temperatureCelsius;
public:
    Temperature(int temperatureCelsius): m_temperatureCelsius { temperatureCelsius }
    { std::cout << "A()" << '\n'; }

    int GetCelsius()
    { return m_temperatureCelsius; }

    int GetFahrenheit()
    { return CelsiusToFahrenheit(m_temperatureCelsius); }
};

Temperature* CreateTemperatureFromCelsius(int c)
{ return new Temperature(c); }

Temperature* CreateTemperatureFromFahrenheit(int f)
{ return new Temperature(FahrenheitToCelsius(f)); }
```

Now if you have different countries and want to register a temperature per country item, you could define countries as follows (note: there are MANY other ways)

```
class BaseCountry
{
    protected:
        Temperature* m_temperature;
    public:
        BaseCountry()
        { }

        virtual ~BaseCountry() = 0; // abstract class

        int GetCountryTemperatureCelsius()
        { return m_temperature ? m_temperature->GetCelsius() : 0; }
}

class CountryA : public BaseCountry
{
    public:
        CountryA(int temperatureC)
        { m_temperature = CreateTemperatureFromCelsius(temperatureC); }

        ~CountryA()
        { delete m_temperature; }
}


class CountryB : public BaseCountry
{
    public:
        CountryB(int temperatureF)
        { m_temperature = CreateTemperatureFromFahrenheit(temperatureF); }

        ~CountryB()
        { delete m_temperature; }
}


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    BaseCountry& c1 = CountryA(10);
    BaseCountry& c2 = CountryB(10);

    // display 10
    std::cout << c1.GetCountryTemperatureCelsius() << '\n';
    // display the number in °C for 10 F
    std::cout << c2.GetCountryTemperatureCelsius() << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

In a display/screen/diagram class, you can hold an array of `CountryBase` references and access their temperature normalized to °C, no matter how they where constructed.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but can I move the `switch` in the initializer list? Also, `B` and `C` call `A` only after `m_z` or `m_p` are calculated based on user input, but maybe I could go around that the way you showed.

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen You can't conditionally call the base constructors. In `D` it is mandatory to call the constructors of all base classes (explicit call or implicit call without parameters), so the switch indicates an underlying design problem.

Comment: Then, I was suggested before to try `unique_ptr`, will that work to dynamically call only one class on a need basis?

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen Maybe you should explain your desired functionality additionally to your planned class layout. Then others can answer, whether the class layout is suitable or not.

Comment: It's the question asked here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38976921/c-instantiate-inside-another-class-a-class-type-variable-from-a-group-of-cla . Suppose I have temperature readings (`A`) from different countries (`B`, `C`, etc), and I have to filter/present/display them on screen/graph/somehow (`D`) (just an example).

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen I added an example, how such a problem could be solved. However, I'm not to sure that it will help you in the end. It starts with the design description... in the temperature example, it might be suitable to focus on the input and output values (in: local temperatures of different countries, out: a graph of temperatures of different countries in a unified measurement unit). Other designs would focus on a desired data structure or dynamic conversion of new input values, ...

Comment: I marked this as the answer even though my real use is different compared to this, but it'll have to serve as a start. In my case `m_x` is a `std::vector`, unknown size until user input, and it's not the only one, `B`, `C`, etc need to call `A()` based on conditionals that cannot be avoided (so no calling `A()` inside the initializer list), and `D` cannot use `unique_ptr` because `A`, even though uses common variables, it's different than `B`&co, but it has to use only one of `B`&co classes at a time. If it's any comfort, it's weird for me, too. Thank you for the answers and patience.

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen a few more thoughts (1) Instead of deciding inside the constructor, make the decision before calling a constructor. (2) Use composition instead of inheritance. Make `A` a pointer variable inside `D` and then conditionally *create* `B` or `C`, but don't inherit `D` from other classes.

Comment: (1) could be done, but there still has to be only one call, any other and it will override `m_x` in `A`. (2) is a bit more difficult since each of `B`, `C`, etc classes have their own math and variables. For example, `B` may use hypergeometric functions, while `C` only basic trigonometry, there is no possible template for them. I think it's fair to say the whole (or)deal is fairly "fluffy". If I give up the constructor for `A` and use a simple member function, and use either `B()` or `C()` inside the initializer list, it works just fine, maybe I should do the same for `B`&co? I'll try.